# What is the difference between compress and cleancss options in grunt-contrib-less?

Tags: css, less, gruntjs

Mates,

I am using grunt-contrib-less for compiling all less files. I found two options doing the same for me.

```
compress: true
```

and

```
cleancss: true
```

What is the difference between these two options? Anything I am missing? Should I be using both or just any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use both, as the docs tell you `compress` Compress output by removing some whitespaces. If you would like more involved minification you should use the Clean CSS option. `compress` option are built in the Less compiler and `clean-css` are separate package.

Currently the Clean CSS option also strips (or does not insert) the `/*# sourceMappingURL=` comment., see: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1656

The Less compiler also has the possibility to pass an option to clean css with `clean-option` grunt-contrib-less does not seems to support this option.

Answer (score 2):

The `cleancss`-option uses the npm-package [`clean-css`](https://npmjs.org/package/clean-css) according to [the documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#cleancss) while my guess would be that `compress` is passed directly to the less-compiler to have it handle minification/compression.

Since I can't see any dependencies on `clean-css` in the `grunt-contrib-less`-package I'm assuming that you will need to install it yourself using `npm install clean-css` if you want to use that option.

Comment: I didn't have to install that clean-css individually but it works, hence m wondering.

What do you mean by pass "compress" to less compiler? Do you have any suggested readings for me about it?

Comment: If you look at the [source for grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/blob/master/tasks/less.js) you will see that it uses the `less`-package to do the actual compiling. If you then look at [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/#usage) you will see that the less-compiler takes an argument called `compress`.

Comment: `clean-css` is a dependency of `less`, however I can' really make it work.